# Simulate Coordinates and fill value based on the closet neighbour [r]

Tags: r, coordinates, simulation

I would like to ask for any advice,

Lets say we have a dataset of coordinates and distrete values, values can represent lets say ratting from 1 to 6,

I need to simulate random coordinates and then give if the values based on the **previously existing** observation in dataset.

Example:

```
library(ggplot2)

size=  100
A <- data.frame(
Long = sample(runif(size, 14.0556, 14.10852), size, replace = F),
Lat = sample(runif(size, 50.0556, 50.10852), size, replace = F),
value = sample(c(1:6), size, replace = T)
)

ggplot(A, aes(Long, Lat))+  
  geom_point(aes(color = factor(value)))
```

Now I would like to fill entire plot area, for example simulate 2000 random coordinates adn then give them value based on the nearesth neighbour from original 100 siye dataset.

Is it possible to simulate this?

Comment: I think it's totally possible to get the values from nearest neighbors, and use them as an estimate. You could write your own logic and functions or research some already existing packages. What have you tried so far?

Comment: "nearest neighbor" to me means that you will need to calculate the distance between all 2000 random coordinates and these 100 coordinates. That's not evil, but ... if this is a smaller sample than what you really have, this scales as a *product* of the sizes. If that's okay, then ... this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/60049868

Comment: Actually, it's a duplicate even if you do scale larger ... it just turns into a different question about *scaling*.

Comment: Pert, once you use the method used in that other answer, use the `apply(dists, 1, which.min)` to get the "rating" number from each of your original coordinates to transplant onto the random coordinates.